# Bounds on the probability measure of a slice

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a probability measure with density, $\rho$, on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and I want to bound
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in [a,b])
$$
where $X_1$ is the first component of the r.v. $X$ with density $\rho$.  I can see that if $\rho$ can be factored as
$$
\rho(x)= \prod_{i=1}^d \rho_{i}(x_i),
$$
and each $\rho_i$ is bounded, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in [a,b])\leq (b-a)\sup_x \rho_1(x).
$$
I'm wondering if something like this holds for more general $\rho$, and how to prove that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), we have that $$P(X_1 \in [a, b]) = \int_a^b \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho(x_1, ... ,x_d) dx_1...dx_d \leq (b-a)\sup_x \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho(x, x_2, ... ,x_d) dx_2...dx_d$$

That is the exact generalisation of your bound for arbitrary $\rho$:

In the particular case, where $\rho(\overline{x}) = \Pi_{i = 1}^d \rho_d(x_d)$ we have

$$(b-a)\sup_x\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho(x, x_2, ... ,x_d) dx_2...dx_d = (b-a)\sup_x\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho_1(x)\rho_2(x_2) ... \rho_d(x_d) dx_2...dx_d = (b-a)\sup_x \rho_1(x) \Pi_{i = 2}^d(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho_i(x_i)dx_i) = (b-a)\sup_x \rho_1(x)$$